# Nodegit and Electron not working together

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nodegit

I am getting this error with nodegit, and I am not sure if it is my fault for not knowing how to work with electron remote or it is a problem with nodegit. I did [file an issue](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/859) just in case.

In my `main.js` file for electron I can use nodegit without any issue.

On the web site I try to use nodegit with `remote`. I get an error. My code:

```
var remote = require('electron').remote;
var pathToRepo = remote.require('path').resolve(currentRepoDir);
remote.require('nodegit').Repository.open(pathToRepo).then(function(repo){
  console.log(repo);
});
```

I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: require(...).remote.require(...).Repository.open is not a function
```

Why is `open` not a function?

Comment: Why are you using `remote` though? The [remote module](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.0/api/remote/) essentially uses RMI which poses a number of shortcomings and generally should not be necessary. Is there a particular reason why you don't require 'path' and 'nodegit' directly, without remote?

Comment: @inukshuk I'll give that a try and update the question. What would be the use case for `remote`?

Comment: In my opinion, the main use case for `remote` is when you need to access some of the Electron modules which are only available to the main process (e.g., remote.app) -- there is no way to require those directly in you renderer process. But node modules are available so there is really no reason I can think of to create them in the main process and access them via RMI unless you wanted to share state between the processes in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `remote.require`?

```
remote.require('path')
```

Just use:

```
require('path')
```

`require` works in the render process too.